# Finding $z=x+y$ such that $x^2 + y^2$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-partitions

For which integers $z$ can one write $z=x+y$ such that $x^2+y^2$ is prime?

It feels like it should be possible for all odd $z>1$, and I have tried to adapt Euler's proof of Girard/Fermat's assertion that any prime congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ can be uniquely expressed as the sum of two squares, but without success.

Comment: Welcome that the site. If you have any doubts on mathematical writing, check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I've removed the [tag:sum-of-squares-method] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this problem is solvable?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A079887 is worth a look. It tabulates the sequence $||x|-|y||$ for the first 85 primes conguent to $1$ mod $4$. (I'm not sure why it stops there; maybe someone will extend it.) This sequence may itself account for all odd numbers (i.e., sums $|x|+|y|$ may not be needed).

Comment: I'm aware of the sum of squares tag summary,  Not sure why you are confident that it isn't relevant.

Comment: I don't know for sure that it's solvable.  I know a retired maths lecturer who reckoned that based on the Prime Number Theorem it was likely that it would hold, and she is hot on number theory.  Her logic was similar to the answer given by Oldboy below.  I thought going back with a proof could give me the edge for once ;-]

Answer (score 5):

Heuristic analysis shows that it's highly likely that your conjecture holds for all odd $z$.

Take an arbitrary odd number $z=2n+1$. The pair of numbers $x,y$ such that $x+y=z=2n+1$ has the minimum sum of squares equal to:

$$s_1=n^2+(n+1)^2=2n^2+2n+1$$

...and the maximum sum:

$$s_2=1^2+(2n)^2=4n^2+1$$

All sums of squares $x^2+y^2$ fall into segment $[s_1,s_2]$ and there are $n$ such sums, from $x=1,y=2n$ up to $x=n,y=n+1$.

The number of primes between $s_1$ and $s_2$ is equal to:

$$n_p=\pi(s_2)-\pi(s_1)$$ and probability that a randomly selected number between $s_1$ and $s_2$ is a prime is approximately:

$$p_n=\frac{\pi(s_2)-\pi(s_1)}{s_2-s_1}=\frac{\pi(4n^2+1)-\pi(2n^2+2n+1)}{2n(n-1)}$$

You have $n$ different sums of squares between $s_1$ and $s_2$ and chances that all of them are composite are approximately:

$$P_n=(1-p_n)^n$$

$$P_n=\left[1-\frac{\pi(4n^2+1)-\pi(2n^2+2n+1)}{2n(n-1)}\right]^n$$

The value of $P_n$ drops sharply when $n$ increases. For example:

$$P_{10}=0.141219$$
$$P_{20}=0.0495773$$
$$P_{100}=0.0000375915$$
$$P_{500}=2.12378\times 10^{-17}$$
$$P_{1000}=6.7996\times 10^{-31}$$
$$P_{10000}=2.23594\times 10^{-229}$$

This proves nothing but is in sync with my numeric experiment that went all the way up to $n=10^7$. It shows that $x^2+y^2$ becomes prime for the first time for comparatively small values of $x$ ($x<<<z$).

Actually, if you plot the smallest value of $x/z$ for which $x^2+(z-x)^2$ is a prime you get a pretty fascinating graph:

[image]

Notice how small the ratio $x/z$ really is. One could conjecture that:

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{x_{min}}{z}=0$$